# How can one create a 'pulse' effect in Processing?

Tags: animation, processing

I am trying to visualize points that appear one by one on a graph I have drawn to the screen.

Ideally, a small ellipse would be drawn first, and from there, a "ring" would move outwards from the center of the ellipse and fade away while it is moving. The initial ellipse would remain where it was originally plotted.

I could code a simple fading ellipse, but am unable to figure out how to animate a moving ring. 
Could anyone please share some ideas on how to get started with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to store the **state** of your animation in a set of variables. Use those variables to draw each frame, and change those variables over time to change what's drawn.

So step one is to figure out what state you need to store. That will tell you what variables you need to keep track of. As a very simple example, you might store a diameter and an opacity:

```java
float diameter = 10;
float opacity = 255;
```

Step two is to use those variables to draw each frame. Only worry about one frame at a time, and in this case we might just clear the old frame and then draw a circle:

```java
 background(0);
 noFill();
 stroke(255, 255, 255, opacity);
 ellipse(width/2, height/2, diameter, diameter);
```

Finally, the last step is to change those variables over time. We can do that by modifying their values to make the circle get bigger and the color to become less opaque:

```java
 diameter++;
 opacity--;
```

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```java
float diameter = 10;
float opacity = 255;

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
 diameter++;
 opacity--;

 background(0);
 noFill();
 stroke(255, 255, 255, opacity);
 ellipse(width/2, height/2, diameter, diameter);
}
```

Please note that **this is just an example**, and you're going to have to apply these steps with your own state and your own variables to achieve the effect you're going for.

Stack Overflow really isn't designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. Try to ask more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. In other words, try something out, and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck. Good luck.